# ASP.NET Core Web app, How can I access HttpContext in startup class for localhost

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1

How can I get the HttpContext in the Startup.cs public void Configure?

this:

```
bool IsLocal = HttpContext.Request.Host.Value.StartsWith("localhost");
```

Gives me the error: CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'HttpContext.Request'.

I need to know if the app is running local or on the server.

Comment: There is no "request" when the application is starting.  And "localhost" *is* "a server".  (Or, another way to look at it, every server is its own "localhost".)  Taking a step back... What's the goal here?  Do you really need to know the difference between "localhost" and "a server", or do you need to know the difference between "development environment" and "production environment"?

Comment: I need to know when I'm on the development machine or on a server. I am accessing a network share and the path is different on the local machine than the server.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1) then.